# methods to collect windows event logs remotely?

Tags: logging, wmi, powershell-2.0

Is there any method faster than wmi available to collect windows event logs remotely using powershell?
If not,how can we make efficient multi-threading wmi-query for collecting logs from multiple hosts?

Answer (score 0):

Look into

```
Get-EventLog
```

You can launch it in a job to multithread it:

```
Start-Job -ArgumentList $HostName { return $(Get-EventLog -ComputerName "$($args[0])" -LogName Application -Source "Source Name") }
```

Then collect all the data:

```
$Logs = $(Get-Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job)
```

Which would look something like this:

```
foreach($HostName in $Hosts) {
    Start-Job -ArgumentList $HostName { return $(Get-EventLog -ComputerName "$($args[0])" -LogName Application -Source "Source Name") }
}

$Logs = $(Get-Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job)
```

Comment: get-eventlog does not provide credential parameter and because of that i'm getting the error of "unauthorized attempt". Alternate is to use invoke-command but it uses http and its slow.

Comment: Unfortunately, invoke-command will be your best bet. If you run them in parallel, the overhead won't be as obvious.

You can also go with WMI and multi-thread them the same way using jobs.